# I have array of array, I want to hit websevice and upload all one array by one to server also after completion of each I want to update the local DB

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have array of array, I want to hit websevice and upload all one array by one to server also after completion of each I want to update the local DB

Comment: This is far too broad of a question. What is the question? How to "hit web service"? How to update local db upon completion? What research have you done? What have you tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I not quite sure what do you trying to do, may be you try something like this?

```
NSArray *arrayOfArrays = ...;
NSURLRequest *request = ...;
for (NSArray *array in arrayOfArrays) {
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
        NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:[NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration]];
        NSData *arrayData = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:array];
        [session uploadTaskWithRequest:request fromData:arrayData completionHandler:^(NSData * _Nullable data, NSURLResponse * _Nullable response, NSError * _Nullable error) {
            //save to local DB
        }];
    });
}
```

Comment: And yes, this is to broad question. If you want to get good answer, you need to get more details about what you have and what do you need. Especially in async operations